# How can I use sessions in codeigniter in more multiples database ?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have a default database that I only use to log in, and after it I change the database using this:

```
$new_db = $this->load->database( $params, TRUE );
$this->db = $new_db;
```

After change database I have to store the session data into the second one but my sessions are storing in the first one and when I try to retrieve it, codeigniter looks for it on the second one.
Does anyone knows why codeigniter has this kind of behavior and some ideia to solve this ? 
Thanks to help.

Comment: If the default database is only used for login, you might want to make the other database the default and only load the login database for logins.

Comment: I can't do it because in my first DB I have some informations about the company and the user. Base on it I load the DB related with the user.

Comment: I think there's some sort of conflict going on because you're overwriting the original $this->db with the new connection. It might work if you use something else (like $this->userdb) instead. Although I can't verify it because I can't seem to reproduce this problem on my test site.

Comment: CI session always make query on `$this->db` and when you assign `$new_db` to `$this->db` your $this->db becoming your second db. You should not assign it. you should keep your default one as it is

Comment: Maybe these responses can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104568/how-do-i-store-database-sessions-in-codeigniter-with-multiple-databases

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to reset session library? It's autoloaded, right? So it won't know the new database values because when the first load happened, your database value was the login database. Try to run `$this->load->library('session');` after changing database.

Since session is actually a class on CI, it would be logical that it maintains the first reference until a new object take place.